# Parity dev node cannot send transactions via web3 py

Tags: parity, web3.py, docker

I'm using a parity dev node via docker with the following set-up:

```
docker run -d -p 8545:8545 parity/parity --config dev --jsonrpc-interface all --jsonrpc-apis all --jsonrpc-cors "*"
```

When I attempt to retrieve balances or create user accounts, it works well. However, when I attempt to send transactions, there is a ReadTimeout exception:

```
    w3.eth.sendTransaction({'to': w3.eth.accounts[1], 'from': w3.eth.coinbase, 'value': 3 * 10**9})
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 268, in sendTransaction
    [transaction],
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 107, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 90, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/gas_price_strategy.py", line 18, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 48, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/attrdict.py", line 18, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 48, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/normalize_errors.py", line 9, in middleware
    result = make_request(method, params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 48, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 48, in apply_formatters
    response = make_request(method, formatted_params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/middleware/exception_retry_request.py", line 87, in middleware
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/providers/rpc.py", line 68, in make_request
    **self.get_request_kwargs()
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/utils/request.py", line 26, in make_post_request
    response = session.post(endpoint_uri, data=data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 555, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 521, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8111): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

I have tested the same `web3.py` code to work well with both `ganache` or `geth --dev`.

**UPDATE:** `web3.js` hangs with a similar request

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
var BN = web3.utils.BN;

web3.eth.getAccounts(async (err, acc) => {
    let startingBalance = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(acc[0]))
    console.log(startingBalance.toString());
    let result = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: acc[0],
        to: acc[1],
        value: 1000000
    })
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parity node is hanging in this instance, because the underlying account has not been unlocked.

Comment: Wow, that sounds broken. I would expect it to return with an error.